# Social media sharing without scripts

Tags: php

I want to share a webpage with social media. I do not want to use plugins, or add JS scripts if I can help it. I just want to use a link in each case.

I have found a [page](http://huebris.com/facebook-share-button/) which explains how to share a webpage in facebook with a link;

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fhuebris.com%2Ffacebook-share-button&t=How+to+Share+Content+from+Your+Website+on+Facebook" target="_blank">this link</a>
```

I have also found how to share on google+ with a link;

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=' . $url . '" ...
```

However, I am looking how to share a page to

- LinkedIn
- Pinterest
- Twitter

as well, but I am coming up short. There seem to be guides on copy/pasting scripts for the share buttons, as well as guides on using each respective API, but for something so simple as using links to post, I cannot seem to find much at all.

Comment: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=your+text+here

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please have a look into these sharing links which works great without javascript for various social sites.

```
<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Share to FaceBook</a>

<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.example.com&text=Simple Share Buttons&hashtags=simplesharebuttons" target="_blank">Twitter</a>

<!-- Google+ -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Google+</a>

<!-- Digg -->
<a href="http://www.digg.com/submit?url=http://www.example.com" target="_blank">Digg</a>

<!-- Reddit -->
<a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://www.example.com&title=Simple Share Buttons" target="_blank">Reddit</a>

<!-- LinkedIn -->
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://www.example.com" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>

<!-- Pinterest -->
<a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">Pinterest</a>

<!-- StumbleUpon-->
<a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://www.example.com&title=Simple Share Buttons" target="_blank">StumbleUpon</a>

<!-- Email -->
<a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share Buttons&Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 http://www.example.com">Email</a>
```

**Update**
I didn't test this href for pinterest, let me know if works or not.

```
<!-- Pinterest -->
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={URI-encoded URL of the page to pin}&media={URI-encoded URL of the image to pin}&description={optional URI-encoded description}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">
    <img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" />
</a>
```

Comment: These look good, just need an alternative for pintrest if possible