# How to make social media share buttons that share custom results from a page?

Tags: php, html

I have a website that gives the user a grade based on the test score, year and season. The results are shown on the page 'result.php'.

I want to add a share button that uses the user input variables score, year and season like so: "In the $seasonInput of $yearInput, with a score of $scoreInput, I would've gotten the grade of .$row->grade.."

What kind of code do I need to achieve this?

EDIT: I'm sharing in Whatsapp, Twitter and Facebook.

Comment: On which social media network(s) will you be sharing?

Comment: You might find this helpful: [Social media sharing without scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548347/social-media-sharing-without-scripts).